# tortoiseSVN filter by author not showing all revisions

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I have a VisualSVN Server running the repo and using the latest TortoiseSVN client on my machine.

The complete log of revisions shows many from a particular user but when I look for that user's name in the filter box I don't get all the revisions that I saw when no filter was applied.  I don't have any options checked (show affected, stop on copy, or include merged).

Is there a setting that I am missing?

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you do in TortoiseSVN Show Log dialog. Could you please elaborate? It also makes sense to check the related TortoiseSVN Manual chapter at http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-showlog.html#tsvn-dug-showlog-filter.